# import nodejs module break my code

Tags: node.js, module, typescript

i have this module:

```
module Net.Server {
    var socket:dgram.Socket;

    [...]
}
```

and this app.ts:

```
var server:Net.Server = new Server();
```

if i write this line at the beginning of the first file:

`import dgram = require("dgram")`

the compiler does not found the type 'Net.Server', why?

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have defined `Net.Server` as an *internal* module, but you are trying to load it as an *external* module.

To use it on Node, you would treat the file as the module:

*Net.Server.ts*

```
export var socket: dgram.Socket;
```